Function space such that $f(x) \geq 1$ almost everywhere is closed
I'm trying to show that the following space is closed:
$$
C := \{f \in L^2([0,1]) : f(x) \geq 1 \text{ almost everywhere } \}
$$
But I'm not really sure. My first thought was to consider $\{f_n\} \subset C$ such that $f_n \to f$ for some $f \in L^2$ and then show that $f(x) \geq 1$ almost everywhere. But I don't think I have enough assumptions here. If each function $f_n$ was bounded, then I could simply use the bounded convergence theorem. That is however, not the case. I could directly use the definition of convergence in $L^2$, but this would give me $|f_n| \geq 1$. How should I proceed? Could I use a Cauchy argument?

Hint: If a sequence converges in $L^2[0,1]$ then it has a subsequence that converges almost surely.

@Mark I'm not really sure to be honest. That seems to bring me back to square one

Not sure of what? You need to show the limit function satisfies $f\geq 1$ almost everywhere. If the type of convergence is almost everywhere then it's not hard to deduce that.

@Mark Yeah that is the thing, I don't know how to deduce that, as easy as its supposed to be... Any idea what am I missing?

@Mark Am I wrong to believe that the convergence of f is done in the L2 norm? That is what I thought convergence would be defined as in this case, and I didnt think to define it as almost everywhere convergence, because we are working in an L2 space and we are talking about C being closed in an L2 sense, right?

Well, for each $n$ let $C_n={f_n<1}$, and also let $C$ be the set of points where $f_n$ doesn't converge to $f$. Then $C\cup(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n)$ has measure zero. What happens on the complement of this union?

See my first comment again. A sequence that converges in $L^2$ has a subsequence that converges almost everywhere. So by passing to a subsequence you may assume the sequence converges both in $L^2$ and almost everywhere.

@Mark yes I see you're deducing it for almost everywhere convergence instead of L2 convergence

@Mark ah sorry I'm stupid, you only need to check a converging subsequence converges almost everywhere. Not the candidate sequence itself.

@Mark ok so on the set $C$ and $C_n$ (for all $n$), my subsequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e. and $f_n \geq 1$ a.e. for every $n$. That's sufficient to know that $f$ is also bounded below by 1 a.e.

Hint: if $f \notin C$, let $A = \{x \in [0,1]: f(x) < 1\}$ which is a measurable set of positive measure.  If $I_A$ is the indicator function of $A$, what can you say about $\int_A I_A(x) (f_n(x)-1) \; dx$ and $\int_A I_A(x) (f(x)-1)\; dx$?

Thanks for the hint. For a start, the second integral is strictly negative. For the first integral, I'm not sure if there is anything immedietely obvious because I can't make a connection between the integrating set defined by $f$ and the sequence $f_n$.

The assumption is that $f_n \in C$, so the first integrand $\ge 0$ almost everywhere.

Here's the completion of Mark's hint in the comments.
Consider $f_{n}$ to be a sequence in $C$ such that $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{2}}f$. To show that $C$ is closed, we need to show that $f\in C$.
So, by Mark's hint, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_{k}}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{a.e.}f$.  i.e. there exist a set $A$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ and for all $x\in A^{c}$, you have $f_{n_{k}}(x)\to f(x)$.
Also, for each fixed $k$, as each $f_{n_{k}}\in C$, there exists $B_{n_{k}}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}(y)\geq 1$ for all $y\in B_{n_{k}}^{c}$ and $\mu(B_{n_{k}})=0$
Note that $\mu\left(A\cup\left(\bigcup_{k}B_{n_{k}}\right)\right)=0$.
So take any $x\in \bigg(A\cup\left(\bigcup_{k}B_{n_{k}}\right)\bigg)^{c}$ and then by definition, you have that $f_{n_{k}}(x)\geq 1$ for each $k$. And hence $f(x)=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}f_{n_{k}}(x)\geq 1$. Thus $f(x)\geq 1$ almost everywhere.
So $f\in C$ and hence $C$ is closed.

The problem is equivalent to showing that the set
$$D=\{f\in L^2(0,1)\,:\, f(x)\ge 0\}$$ is closed, as $C=D+1.$  For $g\in L^2(0,1)$ denote
$B_g=\{x\,:\, g(x)<0\}.$
If $g\notin D$ then $\|g{\bf 1}_{B_g}\|>0.$ For any $f\in D$ and $x\in B_g$ we have $f(x)-g(x)\ge -g(x)=|g(x)|.$ Hence
$$\|f-g\|\ge \|(f-g){\bf 1}_{B_g}\|\ge \|g{\bf 1}_{B_g}\|$$ Therefore the distance from $g$ to $D$ is bounded below by  a positive constant $\|g{\bf 1}_{B_g}\|.$ This means the set $L^2\setminus D$ is open.
